# Get json data from a file

Tags: javascript, json

I wan't to get data from a json file without knowing exacly where the data is:
I have this json

```
    var names= [
{
 "category":"category1" ,
     "name1":"david",
     "name2":"jhon",
     "name3":"peter"
},
{
 "category":"category2" ,
     "name1":"Smith" ,
     "name2":"Anna",
}
]
```

suppose i have a string variable:

```
var str='category2';
```

how can i get category2.name1 using the variable?
I don't want to use names[1].name1 because i don't know whats in str and i want to avoid using for loop.

Comment: with out a loop, not possible

Answer (score 0):

There are some build-in functions that may help you. For example:

```
var matchingElements = names.filter(function(object, index, array) { 
  return object.category == str;
});
```

What you're looking for will always be in `matchingElements[0].name1` if `matchingElements.length > 0`.